# sed append text obtained from stdout

Tags: bash, sed

I know `sed` can append text in a few different ways:

1. to append the string `NEW_TEXT`:

   ```
   sed -i '/PATTERN/ a NEW_TEXT' file
   ```
2. to append contents of file `file_with_new_text`:

   ```
   sed -i '/PATTERN/ r file_with_new_text' file
   ```

However, is there anyway to append text piped to `sed` via stdout?  I am hoping to obtain the equivalent of:

```
# XXX,YYY,ZZZ are line numbers
# The following appends lines XXX-YYY in file1
# after line ZZZ in file2.

sed 'XXX,YYY p' file1 > /tmp/file
sed -i 'ZZZ r /tmp/file' file2
```

without having to use a temporary file.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read from `/dev/stdin`. Clearly, this will only work once per sed process.

Example:

```
$ cat file1
this is text from file1
etc

$ cat file2
Hello world from file2

$ sed -n '1p' file1 | sed -i '$ r /dev/stdin' file2

$ cat file2
Hello world from file2
this is text from file1
```

Comment: One can also write to stdout: `1w/dev/stdout`

Comment: @that other guy : This works.  What do you mean by "this will only work once per sed process"? What is an example that wouldn't work?

Comment: @jayflo the same way i.e. `r/dev/stdout`. It just provides a way to be able to alter file1 and file2 inline.

Comment: @jayflo `echo "This text is only added after the first line, because you can't rewind pipes and read it again for the next line." | sed -i 'r /dev/stdin' file`

Comment: @jayflo: If you want to read again you can use same **process substitution** as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use redirection operator with `r` command:

```
sed -i '/ZZZ/r '<(sed -n '1p' file1) file2
```